# Adding information from one polygon to the attribute table of another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table

I would like for the watershed (blue) attribute table of this map to have a column that indicates what protected area (red) it overlaps with. (As you can see, multiple watersheds touch each protected area).
I have searched around and am unable to figure out how to do this using ArcMap 10.1.  Any suggestions or links to solutions would be awesome!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a Spatial Join to create a new feature class with a combination of attributes and geometry from your original layers. Select your destination geometry, and the attributes you want to join to it from the input layers.